# How to retrieve data from a local var

Tags: javascript, html

i have this script in my html code

```
 <script typre="text/javascript">
        var img = new Array();
        img[0] = new Image();
        img[0].src = "../images/poggiatesta2.jpg";
        img[1] = new Image();
        img[1].src = "../images/poggiatesta1.JPG";
        for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            var imagetag = document.createElement("img");
            var onclick = document.createAttribute("onclick");
            onclick.value = "myfun("+i+")";

            var sorc = document.createAttribute("src");
            sorc.value = img[i].src;

            var id = document.createAttribute("id");
            id.value = "my_image" + i;

            var clas = document.createAttribute("class");
            clas.value = "my_image_clas";

            imagetag.setAttributeNode(clas);
            imagetag.setAttributeNode(onclick);
            imagetag.setAttributeNode(sorc);
            imagetag.setAttributeNode(id);
            document.body.appendChild(imagetag);
        };
        function myfun(i) {
            var src1 = document.getElementById('my_image' + i).src;
            alert(src1);

        }
        </script>
```

It allows me to store the src of a selected image in a var. Now im trying to do a check, which means an alert message that pops out if i didnt select any images like this:

```
 function controllo() {

    if ((src1 == "") || (src1 == "undefined")) {
        alert("Select an image.");
    }
    else {
        location.href = "schienale.html";
    }
}
```

Here's the problem, src1 is a local var, how can i retrieve its data in order to complete my check funcion?

Comment: Where is `controllo` called from?

Comment: From an external .js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store `src1` as a global (it is better to use a [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript), but for the sake of this question a global will do)

```
<script typre="text/javascript">
    var src1; //Notice i've declared the variable here.
    var img = new Array();
    img[0] = new Image();
    img[0].src = "../images/poggiatesta2.jpg";
    ...
```

Then in `myFunc` do:

```
function myfun(i) {
     src1 = document.getElementById('my_image' + i).src;
     alert(src1);
}
```

This will make `src1` available everywhere.

Or, if possible, pass src1 into your `controllo` function.
This is the preferred method because it prevents cluttering the global namespace, but will require the code to be changed elsewhere.
This might help give you a hint though:

```
controllo(src1)    

function controllo(src1) {

if ((src1 == "") || (src1 == "undefined")) {
        alert("Select an image.");
    }
    else {
        location.href = "schienale.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: It was so simple ahah! Thank you very much dude! :)

Comment: No problem. Which solution did you go for? If it helped you, please mark it as correct. I would recommend looking at namespacing. It helps get rid of problems like this. :)

Comment: I went for the global src1 :)